# jquery ui slider doesnt show up when called from angular ui route

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ui-router

this code works properly when i called it without angular ui router. but when i use angular ui router link to this code, it doesn't works anymore. I have included jquery.ui.theme.css,jquery.ui.slider.css,jquery-ui.css

```
<html>
<head> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#slider1').slider({
            value:12,
            min: 10,
            max: 20,
            step: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#font_size').val(ui.value + ' px');
                $('.box').css('font-size', ui.value);
            }
        });
        }); 
    </script>
</head> 
    <body>
    <div class="examples">
        <div class="column">
            <p>
                <label for="font_size">Font size:</label>
                <input type="text" id="font_size" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
            </p>
            <div id="slider1"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">A man bribes a rabbit with wicked dentures to run away with him in a sailboat via an ambulance.</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my ui route

```
myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {     
        $stateProvider
            .state('detail', {                
                url: '/{examID}',              
                views: {
                '': {
                  templateUrl: '/test.html',
                   controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'utils',

                    function ( $scope,$stateParams,utils) {
                      utils.findById($stateParams.examID).success(function (response) {
                      $scope.exam = response;
                    });}
                    ]
            }            
                }
            }     )    

        }])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ':examID' instead of {examID}

Find the code below

```
myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {     
            $stateProvider
                .state('detail', {                
                    url: '/:examID',              
                    views: {
                    '': {
                             templateUrl: '/test.html',

                        }            
                    }
                })    

            }])
```